# How to configure div position based on another div bottom position?

Tags: html, css

I try to put "datacontain" div below "blue-div", but when blue-div height ++, it covers the "datacontain" div,
how to make "datacontain" div position responsive to blue-div bottom part position ?

Result :

[image: when label is short]

[image: when label is long and cover datacontain] -> i want to make the phonenumber (datacontain div) below blue-div

//style

```
<style>
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  .blue-div {
    max-width: 70%;
    min-width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:-12%;
    /* /transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #003777;
    z-index: 130;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  .white-cont {
    width: 80%;
    height: 215px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -25px;
    /* /transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 1px #888888;
  }

  .container-sk {
    position: relative;
   
  }

  .input-group-addon {
    color: gray;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .datacontain {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .submitButton{
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ef7c24;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

//html

```
    <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/img/banner.jpg' ?>" alt="Nature" class="responsive">

    <div class="container-sk flex-container" style="background-color:#28abe3; min-height:300px">
      <div class="white-cont">
        <div class="datacontain col-md-12">
          <div class="">

            <label>phonenumber</label>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  <img style="height:20px;width:20px" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/img/flag.png' ?>">
                  +62
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
              <button class="submitButton" type="button"> KLAIM VOUCHER </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="blue-div" style="">
        <label style="color:#fff;font-size:14px;display:table-cell;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: middle;" >this is voucher 12345 12345 12354 12345 12345 1234 1234 1234 1234 345 345345 345 345 3 </label>
      </div>

      </div>
      
      
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `position: absolute;` on both the blue div and the white container. If you want the blue div to appear first you also need to move it before the white container in your code.

```css
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  .blue-div {
    max-width: 70%;
    min-width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:-12%;
    /* /transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    background-color: #003777;
    z-index: 130;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  .white-cont {
    width: 80%;
    height: 215px;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 1px #888888;
  }

  .container-sk {
    position: relative;
   
  }

  .input-group-addon {
    color: gray;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .datacontain {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .submitButton{
    border-radius: 35px;
    display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ef7c24;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="container-sk flex-container" style="background-color:#28abe3; min-height:300px">
        <div class="blue-div" style="">
        <label style="color:#fff;font-size:14px;display:table-cell;word-wrap: break-word;vertical-align: middle;" >this is voucher 12345 12345 12354 12345 12345 1234 1234 1234 1234 345 345345 345 345 3 </label>
      </div>

      <div class="white-cont">
        <div class="datacontain col-md-12">
          <div class="">

            <label>phonenumber</label>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                  +62
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
              <button class="submitButton" type="button"> KLAIM VOUCHER </button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>
      
      
     
    </div>
```